# Yandex Map for iOS

Tags: ios, yandex, yandex-api

I need to integrate in my iOS app Yandex Map. Do you have a good examples? I use https://github.com/yandexmobile/yandexmapkit-ios, but it doesn't help me. How can I init YMKMapView? Please help me.
Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you looked at the sample project `YandexMapKitSample` provided there? It shows pretty much everything you need.

I also hope you did request a key from Yandex to use the iOS Kit - I've been waiting for mine for about a week or so. You need to put it here: `-[YMKConfiguration setApiKey:]`

Comment: I use this samples and in result, I have error "YandexMapKitSample[3911:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIView 0xb057b40> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key delegate" - I set the key, which i get from yandex in  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:apiKey forKey:kYandexMapKitApiKey];

Comment: @someone Why use NSUserDefaults when you can set the key where it is written in the docs? And also, I think, you should use something like `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:apiKey forKey:@"yandexKey"]`

Comment: Thank you, now I have a problems with displaying mapView "Unknown class YMKMapView in Interface Builder file.". Do you have a tutorial? Could you help me, thank you.

Comment: Thank you, all for helps, if someone have problems with Yandex Map:
  1.https://github.com/yandexmobile/yandexmapkit-ios/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-Yandex-Map-Kit-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82
   2. [[Settings sharedSettings] setApiKey: @"Your api key"];
    _mapView = [YMKMapView new];
    [_mapView setFrame: self.view.frame];
    [_mapView setTracksUserLocation: YES];
    [_mapView setShowsUserLocation: YES];
    [_mapView setShowTraffic: NO];
    [self.view addSubview: _mapView];

Comment: @someone Please mark the answer as accepted if I was able to help you in any way! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you have added flag "-all_load" to Other Linker Flags in project settings?